# Error 'dia' undeclared (first use in this function) oque fazer?

Tags: c

Oque posso fazer? a variável não foi declarada na função?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que passou pela sua cabeça ao fazer `validacao = dia, mes, ano>0;`? Reveja a sintaxe utilizada pela linguagem C. Você está fazendo um `return Data;` mas não definiu a variável `Data`.

Comment: Na segunda linha da função Data vc está usando o operador `,` (vírgula). Ele funciona para concatenar instruções e retorna o valor da última. `validacao = dia, mes, ano>0` seria o mesmo que `dia != 0; mes != 0; validacao = ano > 0;`, ou seja, n faz sentido nenhum. O certo seria `validacao = dia > 0 && mes > 0 && ano > 0;`. Em `void main()` vc precisa criar as variaveis `int dia, mes ano;` e em `int Data()` vc precisa retornar um número inteiro.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que declarar as variáveis dia, mês e ano dentro da main pra poder mandar elas como parâmetros da função.

A validação dentro da int Data precisará ser um condicional: `if(dia > 0 && mes > 0 && ano > 0)` se entrar nesse if você dá um `return 1;` para verdadeiro e no `else` um `return 0;` para falso.
Na main você verifica `if(Data(dia, mes, ano) == 1)`, caso entre nessa condição você chama a função `int valido` que precisará de parâmetros também.

Ficará assim:

```
    int data(int dia, int mes, int ano)
{
    if(dia > 0 && mes > 0 && ano > 0)
        return 1; //Os valores são válidos.
    else
        return 0; //Algum dos valores ou todos são inválidos.
}

int valido(int dia, int mes, int ano)
{
    printf("Curitiba, %i/%i/%i \n", dia, mes, ano);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int dia, mes, ano;
    printf("Digite o dia, mes e ano consecutivamente: ");
    scanf("%i %i %i", &dia, &mes, &ano);
    if(data(dia, mes, ano) == 1)
    {
        printf("\nA data eh: \n\n");
        valido(dia, mes, ano);
    }
    else
        printf("\nValores invalidos. \n");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]